# How to update attribute of xml based on textbox value in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I will appreciate your help with this one.

I've written a code to enable me to modify the attribute of an xml element based on the value in the textbox.

Everything seems to work when debugged, but upto the last code, as the xml file deos not get updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            doc.Load("Info.xml");

            XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            ns.AddNamespace("root", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
            XmlNode Body = doc.SelectSingleNode("//root:Body", ns);
            ns.AddNamespace("child", Body.FirstChild.NextSibling.NamespaceURI);

            XmlNode nodeIr = doc.SelectSingleNode("//child:Name", ns);

            nodeIr.InnerText = txtBox1.Text;

            doc.Save("Info.xml");

        }
```

I believe the last line needs to be modified.

Thank you

Comment: Can node `nodeIr' be null?

Comment: Maybe file Info.xml read-only. Add try-catch to get full error info.

Comment: Why do you believe the last line needs to be modified? You mean `doc.Save("Info.xml");`?

Comment: nodelr is not null, it is showing the value in the textbox.

Comment: I've just added try catch, & it does read the line but the xml is not updated. @BrootsWaymb, the code doc.save(info.xml") does not seem to be saving the update. Or am I missing something else in the code?

Comment: @Jonbx - just for the sake of eliminating the obvious, what if you save as a new file? If you change that line to something like `doc.Save("Info2.xml");` do you get a new file?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, I've just tried that and it has not saved a new file.  I think the problem is that I'm trying to save the xml within the project. I've tried updating and saving to the c drive and it works. Thanks